# KStream aggregate fixed list (limited size)

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I would love to wonder if its possible (supported by default) to add aggregation for particular batch of messages that has been received from particular topic.

*#description*:  I have players that are looking for a lobby which is created automatically. The idea is a player runs a search for a game and the message with { id, mod, map } is sent to the topic. Each mod/map contains a rule how many players can be allowed to join and based on that amount I am trying to aggregate those players. When the status of lobby (game) looks like is ready to launch a lobby (10/10 players) we should convert details to a single message and push this further to handle and at the same time aggregation should be refreshed and started from 0.

```
KStream<String, List<String>> gameLobbyEventStream =
    streamsBuilder.stream(
            "GAME_MATCHMAKING_LOBBY_EVENT-TOPIC",
            Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.serdeFrom(String.class)))
        .peek((k, v) -> log.info("key:{}, value:{}", k, v))
        .groupBy((k, v) -> k, Grouped.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()))
        .aggregate(
            ArrayList::new,
            (k, v, agg) -> {
              agg.add(v);
              return agg;
            },
            Materialized.with(
                Serdes.String(), Serdes.ListSerde(ArrayList.class, Serdes.String())))
        .toStream();

gameLobbyEventStream
    .filter((k, v) -> isReadyToStartLobby(v))
    .peek((k, v) -> log.info("lobby is creating for {}", v))
    // convert to lobby { id, players, details }
    .to("LAUNCH_MATCHMAKING_LOBBY_EVENT-TOPIC");
```

*#real case*: mode: deathmatch (**3x3** : **6** players allowed)

```
 -> player-1 clicked to find a game
 -> player-2 clicked to find a game   
 -> player-3 clicked to find a game  
 -> player-4 clicked to find a game  
 -> player-5 clicked to find a game
 -> player-6 clicked to find a game

 -> lobby has been created for players above {aggregation finished}

 -> player-7 clicked to find a game
 -> player-8 clicked to find a game
 -> {aggregation status: **2** of **6** to create new lobby}
```

*#note*: there is no time window. If player wants to find a lobby I have to allow him to wait as much as he wants to until he cancels the search.

I am aggregating to the List<> and would like to create a lobby when aggregation (List) size will be equals to expected amount of players for the mod chose.

The issue I am facing with is aggregation is incrementing over and over again without a reset and I see hundreds of players that wait a lobby to start. The behavior I expect is similar to chunks where number of players were pushed to lobby and handled further meanwhile next chunk should aggregate player from zero to expected players amount again as new lobby.

Comment: I don't see any code that checks the size of your list while you're aggregating. IMO, this would be much easier with plain consumer api. In particular, what happens when you consume half the players, then your app crashes? In Streams, it might be auto committing those few players that were never grouped into any lobby. You'd want to rewind the offset back to capture any ungrouped players or fix your commits such that that never happens (only commit when lobbies are formed)

Comment: Thanks for the comment @OneCricketeer. 
First of all I would like to use KStream for this matter as KStream works asynchronous and during creation of lobby it should reduce issues between various instances of service in comparison with a plain API where I need to control everything manually and for sure additionally use distributed cache/ or somehow share players between lobbies on each machine. 
I made a check for the size only after aggregation when I invoke filter and I did not come up with any solution how to trigger aggregation init part again to create new List<Player>.

Comment: Returning back to the topic of failure I assume I will need to capture those players who were potentially in a lobby or leave it as it would be by notifying that search was failed and players need to reran the search (at least for now).
Moreover one more feature to use KStream is a plan to create one more prioritized queue to find a lobby for group of players where someone would like to add a friend to play in the same match. That is how I can achieve the idea by merging these Streams (players who are alone and players in a group)

Comment: I would see more reasonable way to solve the issue instead of the snippet below:
(any suggestions how to solve the problem when one partition is down)

`.aggregate(ArrayList::new,
   (k, v, agg) -> {
       if (agg.size() == 5) {
         return new ArrayList<>(List.of(v));
        }
      agg.add(v);
     return agg;
}`

Comment: If one partition is down, then one of the replicas will be consumed instead. There is nothing that needs added to the code to account for that.

Comment: thanks for participation in the discussion. I am glad to hear a few more issues that you have pointed me out to overthink

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code to deal with expected aggregation of the players list. The issue here is that we might need to stop the search for particular player (he sent an event to stop the search) and it adds a difficulty to decline a lobby you have been recently added to.
(there is an option to manage the case if we notify a client by popup menu with accepting/canceling the lobby as the final decision that approves the decision for these players who are already in lobby)

```
.aggregate(ArrayList::new,
    (k, v, agg) -> {
        if (agg.size() == 5) {
          return new ArrayList<>(List.of(v)); 
        }
       agg.add(v);
      return agg; 
}
```